# Retrofit2 and Moshi: Send JSON without nested objects

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, moshi

On my code i have a data class that store some information to pass to a webservice as json body

```
data class MyDataClass(
    var booleanField : Boolean = true,
    var stringField : String = "",
    var aDataField : ADataClass = ADataClass()
)
```

where ADataClass is a class that i will reuse in my code, like

```
data class ADataClass(
    var aDataString : String = "",
    var aDataAnotherString : String = ""
)
```

Now, when i call my webservice, i pass a json like

```
{
     "booleanField" : true,
     "stringField" : "someValue",
     "aDataField" : {
         "aDataString" : "aString",
         "aDataAnotherString" : "anotherString"
     }
}
```

But json accepted must be like

```
 {
     "booleanField" : true,
     "stringField" : "someValue",
     "aDataString" : "aString",
     "aDataAnotherString" : "anotherString"
}
```

So, there's a way (like some annotation) to avoid creation of **aDataField** element while parsing, and put just it's content inside json?

Answer (score 0):

No you should set it manually

MyDataClass will have one more variable
aDataAnotherString and it's getter and setter methods and then insert it

```
MyDataClass myData = response;
if(myData != null && myData.getADataClass() != null){
    myData.setaDataAnotherString(myData.getADataClass().getaDataAnotherString());
}
```